# What is the equivalent of NumberFormat in JavaScript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, number-formatting

I use formatter for my double values in Java like:

```
private static final NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###0.00");
formatter.format(doubleValue);
```

However I don't want to do it on the server side.  How can I write an equivalent code in Javascript or JQuery?

Comment: But ... JSP is a server-side thing too ...

Comment: "implement it at my jsp file with JQuery or JavaScript" -- it appears you are confused: JSP runs on the server (in fact it is compiled into standard Java code) while JavaScript runs on the client/browser, and jQuery is just a library built using JavaScript.

Comment: @Erick your edits changed his question to something he didn't want. You also overwrote his edits (because they happened at the same time, and you didn't see them.) I reverted to his edits.

Comment: @casablanca JavaScript actually can run on the server, but you're right in that's not what @kamaci is going for. He wants to write some JavaScript into his JSP to be run on the client, or to do it in JSP alone.

Comment: @glowcoder: He said specifically that he doesn't want to do it on the server side.  That means he wants it in the client-side, which means Javscript or JQuery.  I reverted to my edit.

Comment: @casablanca thats what I want to do. @Pointy JavaScript runs on client side so I want to format it at client side.

Comment: @glowcoder you exactly explained what I mean

Comment: @Erick he did specifically say that - he also edited it away because he misspoke. That edit was wiped away by your edit. (I'm not saying you acted wrongly, I'm just saying the foundation on which you based your edits changed before you were aware they had changed.)

Comment: @kamaci: Looks like there was some confusion with concurrent edits. :) @Erick has the solution for you using jQuery.

Comment: @kamaci well it's too bad the guy who knows exactly what you want to do doesn't know jack-patoot about JSP or JavaScript! :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use the [NumberFormatter](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-numberformatter/) plug-in for JQuery.**

FYI: the old link was [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/numberformatter).

Comment: The link is broken, pal.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't mean to offend.  English isn't my native language.  I was only trying to help.

Comment: No problem.  It's a fairly colloquial way to address someone who you don't know. :)  Anyways, it looks like the project was moved into google code, so hopefully this still helps people.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 3):

I know this doesn't really answers your question, but have you thought of using the [jstl formatNumber](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0415/) tag?

Answer (score 1):

Use JSTL `<fmt:formatNumber>` ... http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatnumber_tag.htm

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<fmt:formatNumber type="number" pattern="###0.00" value="${bean.value}" />
```

Comment: this is only going to work when the page is first rendered; cannot run it client side (to format values from JSON or user input for example).

Answer (score 1):

Trying using [sprintf() for JavaScript](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf).

Answer (score 0):

Ext JS's Format class has a `number` function you can use to do this, see [Ext.util.Format](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.util.Format).  As of Ext 4 it also supports  locale-specific "thousand separators".

I guess the downside is that you need to import part of the Ext framework to use it!

Comment: Although I think this can do what you need, it's not as powerful as Java's NumberFormat class.