# jQuery: Convert numeric string in to some standard format

Tags: jquery

Is there any jQuery plugin which convert numeric string into a standard format let say:

```
200000 to 2,00,000
1000 to 1,000
398740 to 3,987,40
```

and so on..

Comment: That is a weird numbering scheme you want

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of NumberFormat in JavaScript or JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170465/what-is-the-equivalent-of-numberformat-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var s = 200000;
var converted = s.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VzSKE/)

or:

```
$.fn.convert = function() { 
    return this.each(function(){ 
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")); 
    })
}
```

you can call it for converting texts of selected elements like other jQuery methods:

```
$('#elem').convert()
```

Comment: it is fine if I used this function with page refresh but if I used it with the response send by AJAX POST firesbug shows the correct HTML <span id="pro_value">232343</span> and function is also there but does not format the numeric string. I think jQuery live() could be used but how I don't know.

Comment: Okay I just bind <script>
  $(document).ready(function (){
   $('#my_value').convert();
  });
 </script>